# PDF Images not displaying in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, pdfkit

Im facing an issue of PDF images not displaying in UIWebView

The way of the logic is, 
 1. UIWebView receives a base64 string
 2. Convert the string to NSData
 3. Load the NSData to the UIWebView

Here is the part of the code

```
NSString *b64 = @"JVBERi0xLjMNCiW9vrwNCjEgMCBvYmoNCjw8DQoJL0Jhc2VGb25...."; 
NSData *d =[[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:b64 options:nil];
[uiWebview loadData:d MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

There is a workaround that i manage to show the images in UIWebView, the workaround is

1. Copy the base64 string to an online converter to convert it to a pdf file
2. Export there pdf file again using Mac Application Preview using 'Export as PDF'
3. Convert the file again to base64 string and display at the UIWebView

But this workaround is not feasible, as i do not have the Preview application in the app

I also notice that, before i 'Export as PDF' in Preview application the pdf is editable such as the images can be drag or deleted.

So my question would be,

1. Did I implement UIWebView code wrongly?
2. Is the any library for 'Export as PDF' for iOS application? I did explore around on PDFKit, but it does seem to have any export function

Answer (score 0):

b64 is of type NSString

initWithBase64EncodedData:b64 options:nil needs as first Parameter NSData.

Try:

```
NSString *b64 = @"JVBERi0xLjMNCiW9vrwNCjEgMCBvYmoNCjw8DQoJL0Jhc2VGb25...."; 
NSData *d =[[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:b64 options:nil];
[uiWebview loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

Or try:

```
[[PDFDocument alloc] initWithData: d];
```

to get a Pdf from your base64 string.

Comment: Hi @ivion, both solution is still not displaying the images

Comment: One possibility: [uiWebview loadData: d MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil]; or is 'data'  just aTypo in the query?

Comment: Hi Ivion, check that is not that issue